# query entities contained in a composite entity in doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `Friendship` class that contains a `$user` and a `$friend`. I'd like to get a list of a all friends for a user. I'm unsure on how to create a query builder to do this.

Here's my yml.

```
Acme\Project\Domain\User\Entity\Friendship:
    type: entity
    table: friendships
    id:
        user:
            associationKey: true

        friend:
            associationKey: true
    fields:
        createdAt:
            type: datetimetz
            column: created_at
    manyToOne:
        user:
            targetEntity: Acme\Project\Domain\User\Entity\User
            joinColumn:
                name: user_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                onDelete: CASCADE
        friend:
            targetEntity: Acme\Project\Domain\User\Entity\User
            joinColumn:
                name: friend_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                onDelete: CASCADE
```

I've tried this

```
    $qb->select('f.friend')
        ->from(Friendship::CLASS, 'f')
        ->where('IDENTITY(f.user) = :user_id')
        ->setParameter('user_id', $user->getId());
```

But get the following error.

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 9 near 'friend FROM Acme\\Project\\Domain\\User\\Entity\\Friendship': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
```

I'm almost certain it's because the select portion contains a ".".

Comment: then if you change your select by select('frd') and add ->join('f.friend', 'frd') after from clause, what happens ?

Comment: `'SELECT frd FROM': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.`

Comment: I've just corrected my previous answer below

Answer (score 0):

OK you have an error "must be a statefield expression" because as you say there is a dot in your select, you select a member of your root variable 'f'.

But in your case I think your mapping is wrond and that's why you encounter difficulties to write your query.
I think you shouldn't have a Friendship class, and some ManyToOne associations.
But only a ManyToMany association in User class with self-referencing

Here from the official doc :

[many-to-many-self-referencing](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing)

I quote :

> You can even have a self-referencing many-to-many association. A
>   common scenario is where **a User has friends and the target entity of
>   that relationship is a User** so it is self referencing. In this
>   example it is bidirectional so User has a field named $friendsWithMe
>   and $myFriends.

You have to translate the following mapping with annotations, to mapping with yml in your case :

```
<?php
/** @Entity **/
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="myFriends")
     **/
    private $friendsWithMe;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friendsWithMe")
     * @JoinTable(name="friends",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="friend_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     **/
    private $myFriends;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->friendsWithMe = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->myFriends = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```

And the query :

```
$qb->select('u')
    ->from(User::CLASS, 'u')
    ->join('u.friendsWithMe', 'friendWithMe')
    ->where('IDENTITY(friendWithMe) = :user_id')
    ->setParameter('user_id', $user->getId());
```

Comment: i need the `Friendship` entity to be able to determine how long the users have been friends and other meta data about that relationship

Comment: ok I didn't see the time and created_at fields, can you add your User entity mapping ?